# Pushing manually initialized view controller freezes app

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

I'm initializing a view controller and pushing it like so

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES]
```

However, the app basically freezes after pushing. If I don't push, it doesn't transition to the new view, but I can continue using the app (it doesn't freeze).

Also, if I add a view controller to my storyboard of class MyViewController and give it a storyboard Id, I can initialize the view controller and push it just fine with the storyboard `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` method.

Anybody have any idea why this is happening?

**Edit**

Using the technique that Zaph recommended in his comment, I can see that the code is stuck iterating the new view controller's `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method over and over. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Hit the break button in Xcode and see what and where you are, look at the stack trace. Do it multiple times.

Comment: Where is this break button? The pause button?

Comment: It's stuck in the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method of the new view controller, everytime I pause it's in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use alloc/init for a view controller. You either need to load it from a storyboard or an XIB file. If you're loading it from a storyboard, you'd use instantiateViewController:withIdentifier. If you're loading it from an XIB, you want to use initWithNibName:bundle:

Comment: So this means even if I don't want any of the benefits of using the interface builder, I still have to drag out a view controller and give it a storyboard id and instantiate it that way? I've never used xib files I don't think....

Comment: I tried the method in my question after reading [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication.html), section labeled "Instantiating a Non-Storyboard View Controller"

Comment: oh my god, i just created a view controller class with XIB, can't believe i've never seen this before..

Comment: Interface Builder is your friend.

Answer (score -1):

Try and hit COMMAND + 7 if you are running Xcode 5 (COMMAND + 6 on Xcode 4) to show all your break points. Then delete all breakpoints because it sounds like you are frozen on a break point.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No break points, like I said if I comment out the 2nd line, everything works fine (except it doesn't transition). I understand that's not conclusive that there aren't any breakpoints, but trust me, there are none.